# How the accuracy of a meter bridge is increased?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, error-analysis

It is said that the accuracy of a meter bridge is increased if the null point is nearly in the middle. Why is it so? How to prove it mathematically?

Comment: Usually when symmetry results in higher accuracy, it is because some errors are being cancelled out somewhere. It is not necessarily a mathematical fact that can be analyzed using an ideal circuit. It may be inaccuracies non-idealities in of a real circuit with real physical components that is being canceled out.

Comment: Is this question about the precision or sensitivity or accuracy of the bridge?

Comment: @Farcher  Yes it is.

Comment: @GarvChaudha - all three? Precision, sensitivity, and accuracy are different things.

Comment: @JonCuster it is about the accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know this device. I answer simply, in the case where the uncertainty of the measurement is mainly related to the uncertainty on the position.
The resistance to be measured $R$ is : $$R=S \frac{x}{L-x}$$ The logarithmic differential is written : $$\frac{dR}{R} = \frac{dx}{x} - \frac{d(L-x)}{L-x} = dx \frac{L}{x(L-x)}$$
And so, passing to the uncertainties: $$\frac{\delta x}{x} = \delta x \frac{L}{x(L-x)}$$
The product $x(L-x)$ is maximal for $x = L/2$ which minimizes the relative uncertainty.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.